# Adding MVC to an empty ASP.NET 5 project in VS2015: Empty 500 Responses

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a minimal MVC6 (I guess MVC Core now?) project in Visual Studio 2015, by starting with an empty project and adding the MVC bits - I don't need a lot of the extra guff that's added as part of the "Web App" project, and I want to learn by doing, so am trying the following method. Unfortunately every request to this web app results in a 500 internal error response with no further details.

1. Create a new ASP.NET 5 empty web project. This starts with the "Hello World!" response for all requests
2. Add the following line to project.json:

> ```
> "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
> ```

3. Modify the code in Startup.cs as follows:

> ```
> public class Startup
>        {
>             public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
>             {
>                 services.AddMvc(); // ADDED
>             }
>
>             // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
>             public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
>             {
>                 app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
>
>     // REMOVED
>     //            app.Run(async (context) =>
>     //            {
>     //                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
>     //            });
>
>                 app.UseMvc(config =>
>                 {
>                     config.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
>                         new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
>                 });
>             }
>
>             // Entry point for the application.
>             public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
>         }
> ```

4. Add a Controllers folder with HomeController.cs:

> ```
> public class HomeController : Controller
> {
>     // GET: /<controller>/
>     public IActionResult Index()
>     {
>         return View();
>     }
> }
> ```

5. Add a Views folder, with _Viewstart.cshtml in the root:

> ```
> @{
>     Layout = "_Layout";
> }
> ```

6. Add Views/Shared folder with _Layout.cshtml (My actual app is an angular2 app so has a lot more static content than this)

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
>
> <html>
> <head>
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
>     <title>My Test App</title>
> </head>
> <body>
>     <div>
>         Testing
>     </div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

7. Add Views/Home/Index.cshtml with content:

> ```
> @{
>     ViewBag.Title = "My Test App";
> }
> <div>Testing</div>
> ```

But when I run this, I get a 500 Internal error response for every request, with no error messages or content that I can see to indicate what might be wrong? Any ideas what may be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have my answer to this. I actually found it as I putting the finalising touchs on the question, so I thought I'd post them if anyone else has similar issues.  It seems that if you forget to put a @RenderBody call in _Layout.cshtml, then you get a 500 internal error and nothing obvious that tells you what is wrong!  The fix was just to add the @RenderBody() to _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>My Test App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```